# Вопрос к Гуру как можно сделать текстовый консольный редактор на си

Tags: c

Пока не придумал с чего можно начать. Нужно сделать текстовый редактор. Ввод-вывод текста через консоль. Охота подсветку скобок. Каких-то основных функций конструкций.
Подскажите что почитать, что посмотреть.

Comment: Посмотрите исходники каких-нибудь простых редакторов, например, [nano](https://github.com/madnight/nano)

Answer (score 0):

> Подскажите что почитать, что посмотреть.

Все ваши желания реализуются с помощью библиотеки ncurses. Для начала, посмотрите сюда :

http://alexber220.narod.ru/ncurses/

Comment: боюсь ему нужно с нуля.

Comment: ncurses не подойдет. Нужно что то другое.

Comment: @zhilenkov, нужно больше подробностей. Что вы хотите в результате? Как это будет работать? Как это будет выглядеть. Много есть редакторов: строчные, экранные, командные. Что вам нужно?

Comment: Мне нужен текстовый редактор для написания и редактирования кода. Реализован он должен на языки си, компилироваться в gcc. Нужно иметь возможность перехватить ввод и вывод данных. Реализовывается проект будет на микроконтроллере и нужно через терминал править команды управления.

Comment: @zhilenkov а как планируется подключатся к микро? Не совсем понимаю, это же не полноценная железка где можно подрубиться по ssh и отредактировать файл, В моем представлении это всегда редактирование данных на компе и прошивка через программатор, в какой момент тут появляется редактор на самом микро?

Comment: В микроконтроллер будет встроена система команд. Элементарные функции, получения данных, передача данных, команды сравнения, циклы и так далее. Перед программистом  будит стоять задача с использованием этих команд написать программный код для управления какой либо системой лифт допустим. В мк уже встроена прошивка с системой команд. Задача сделать текстовый редактор этих системных команд. Чтобы можно было через консоль вводить данные команды редактировать их, сохранять, и так далее. Желательно видео vga . Интерфейс ком-порт.

Comment: @zhilenkov если интервейс - компорт, то почему не использовать толстый редактор на компьютере и заливать программу через xmodem?

Comment: Нужен ещё и редактор через ком порт.

Comment: Что думаете об linenoise ?